# Ubuntu lost Sudo password

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

After a disk crash someone reinstalled Ubuntu for me.  My su password works.  They said they used no sudo password, but that doesn't work, and nothing else works.  Can I reset the sudo password from the terminal?  And if, how would I do that?  I'm pretty new to linux, so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In general `sudo` is using your user using to login e.g. into your desktop password. Giving sudo is installed, you might need to add your user to group `sudo`. This can be done as root via e.g.

```
usermod -a -G sudo your_user_name
```

Having this done, sudo should work for your user again. However, if you have a full root account -- I assume this from your su is working -- you don't need `sudo` as you could use e.g. `su` with `-c` command. But this is more kind of taste and what exactly you are doing.

P.S. Maybe you can have a look at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: askubuntu.com is not the right place to ask this. This is not strictly Ubuntu related.

Comment: hmmmm... as he might is a ubuntu-user, having a look there is a good idea nevertheless. Also configuration of Ubuntu e.g. on sudo is also differing form other distributions ....

Comment: @frlan Debian has the same configuration.

Comment: Well.. even on Debian there have been differences at least in past. Not sure about the current state and I really it's OT here at this point.

Comment: It is **not off topic** here.  Just because it may fit on other sites as well or better doesn't mean that it is off topic here.  The topic of this site is general personal computing issues, this certainly fits.

Comment: The discussion of sudo configuration of Debian and Ubuntu is at least off topic for this question.

Comment: Hi Guys,  Someone called me with a method for changing my SUDO pw from the root.  This appears to have solved the problem.  I really do need the SUDO password as I am doing various work from the graphical interface and it keeps demanding that; much of this work I don't know how to do from the terminal.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no "sudo-password". It's users's password and of cause this can be changed with e.g. passwd from root.

Answer (score 0):

Or at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo :

> Just remember, when sudo asks for a password, it needs YOUR USER
>   password, and not the Root account password.